# apt upgrade package stats summary wording

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, upgrade

For some reason, the package stats summary line looks different on my machine to others that I have seen and, from what I can tell, also the source code.

```
$ sudo apt upgrade --assume-no
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

The summary line shows:

- `to upgrade`
- `to newly install`
- `to remove`
- `not to upgrade`

The source code appears to show:

- `upgraded`
- `newly installed`
- `to remove`
- `not upgraded`

[apt-private/private-output.cc](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/apt/apt.git/tree/apt-private/private-output.cc?h=1.2.26#n634)

```
  634    ioprintf(out,_("%lu upgraded, %lu newly installed, "),
  635         Upgrade,Install);
  636 
  637    if (ReInstall != 0)
  638       ioprintf(out,_("%lu reinstalled, "),ReInstall);
  639    if (Downgrade != 0)
  640       ioprintf(out,_("%lu downgraded, "),Downgrade);
  641 
  642    ioprintf(out,_("%lu to remove and %lu not upgraded.\n"),
  643         Dep.DelCount(),Dep.KeepCount());
```

LSB info

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
```

On another Xenial host I see the expected line:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Does anyone know where this different wording is appearing from?

Installed version:

```
apt is /usr/bin/apt
apt: /usr/bin/apt
apt:
  Installed: 1.2.26
  Candidate: 1.2.26
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.26 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.2.15ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.2.10ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Have you checked where your `apt` is coming from? Add the output of  `type -a apt; dpkg -S $(command -v apt); apt-cache policy apt`, please

Comment: Which locale are you using? Do you get the same output with `sudo env LC_ALL=C apt upgrade`?

Comment: @muru thanks, indeed it does appear that the locale is behind the change - what isn't clear is why they differ - "upgraded" and "to upgrade" are quite different

Comment: I wonder what locale you're on. `apt`'s source doesn't include separate translations for English dialects, and the string `to upgrade` doesn't appear in any of the other locales' translation files either.

Comment: It's set to en_GB.UTF-8. I couldn't see a translation either